# Cannot import win32com.client module. Python Version 3.5.1 (32 bit)

Tags: python-3.x

I am having an issue importing the client module after installing the pywin32 extension for windows. I can import win32com with no issues at all, but I recieve an error when I try importing the client module. I realize this question has been asked numerous times, but here is what I have tried:

1. I have installed and reinstalled the correct version of pywin32. I have Python version 3.5 (32 bit) and I have installed the 3.5 32 bit file.
2. I have updated my PATH variable and my PYTHONPATH variable to include the locations of both the win32com and the client module.
3. I've manually ran the postinstall win32com script (not sure what this would do but I've read that it has helped some people)
4. It is worth noting that I can import sys, os, win32com, and win32com.client in the python IDLE, but when I  run the import from a script in the same format, Python tells me it can't find the win32com.client module.

I receive the following error when running the win32com.client import from a  script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\10023539\Desktop\pyscripts\outlook.py", line 3, in <module>
import win32com.client
ImportError: No module named 'win32com.client'; 'win32com' is not a package
```

I'm not sure what else to try at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you rename the client module just to test that maybe it is some sort of a naming conflict?

Comment: Sorry for the beginner question but do you mean just renaming the client folder within the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\win32com" path?

Comment: Yes and import it via the new name, this way you can at least see if it is importing what you are expecting.

Comment: I renamed the folder to clientx and tried to import, I still received the same error. It's strange, I think I've isolated the client module to be the issue since I've run other scripts with just win32com with no problems.

Comment: Another thing to check is if there is a "client" folder under win32com module. Since when you import using a dot notation, it is looking for that folder structure.